# What games are based around single historical events?

Tags: game-design, historical-settings

I recently came across the game [Montsegur 1244](http://thoughtfulgames.com/montsegur1244/), which I think looks rather interesting, and it made me wonder whether there are any other games that centre around a single historical event in that way.

There would seem to be a lot of interesting possibilities - terrorist attacks or political coups in the modern day, or older events like the Great Fire of London, the Salem Witch Trials or the Mutiny on the Bounty. Any known examples published to date?

Comment: Montsegur 1244 is a brilliant game. One of my absolute favorites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Grey Ranks](http://www.bullypulpitgames.com/games/) is based around the 1944 Warsaw Uprising.

Comment: Ooooh....And I was going to be so clever by giving that answer!

Comment: Thanks Graham - on reflection, I knew that, but it's good to be reminded!

Comment: Accepting this on the basis that more people seem to have found it helpful.

Answer (score 5):

[Roanoke](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/12/12592.phtml) is about the disappearance of the [Roanoke colony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roanoke_Colony) in America.

Comment: Another good one. I remember this game now you mention it, but had completely forgotten about it while writing the question, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Holistic Designs has a series of D20 supplements set in contemporary hot spots: Afghanistan, Colombia, and Somalia.

In the mid-eighties a game set in Salem in the 1690's was produced called [Witch Hunt](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/12/12119.phtml); it is long out of print.